# Unity call android static function of java class

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine

Hi i'd like to call this piece of android java code in unity with c# here the java code:

```
SmsDialog.getInstance().init(this);
//this is context of android activity
```

And right now  i'm doing it like this in my c# code:

```
void ShowPaymentDialog()
{

    AndroidJavaClass smsDialog = new AndroidJavaClass("com.mobagym.testsdkmobagym.SmsDialog");
    smsDialog.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("getInstance").Call("init",getContext());
}
AndroidJavaObject getContext()
{
    AndroidJavaClass jc = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject jo = jc.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    return jo;
}
```

There are no crashes or anything, Just that game stops and doesnt execute lines after ShowPaymentDialog.

```
void Start () 
{
    ShowPaymentDialog();
    GoogleAnalyticsV4.getInstance().LogScreen(MyMenuManager.SPLASH_SCREEN);
    StartCoroutine(Next());
}
IEnumerator Next()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
    SceneManager.LoadScene(MyMenuManager.MAIN_MENU);
}
```

so i'd like to know if i'm doing sth wrong **with c# syntax.** And if there are any ways to log this.

Comment: Very likely a null or exception problems on your Java side. You think it's not important to post your Java code? Maybe we should figure out what that Java code looks like?

Comment: thnx , java code works fine in android studio :D i've tested it .

Comment: It doesn't matter. Although it must work in Android Studio but that does **not** mean it will work with Unity. There are many reasons why it wouldn't but without your code, it's all guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to log the error as you mention.
Try setting up a try catch block.

```
Try {
    //do some logic
} catch (Exception e){
    //Log exception
}
```

Check this link:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.LogException.html

Maybe when you have stacktrace with exact error we can provide more assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably having a native java exception and missing it. You should connect a device to it and monitor the device log with `adb logcat` looking for your method call. This should give you enough information to continue debugging.